# PayPal IPN response invalid after sending post data back using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

My PayPal IPN code receives the post data sent back from PayPal upon purchase completion but doesn't insert the data into the database. I had the code send me an email if it fails to insert the data into the database. If I take that post data and paste it into the address bar after ipn.php?, it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to post the data back to PayPal?

**My IPN Listener**

```
    <?php
include 'includes/class.user.php';
$user = new USER();
$emailtext = "";

$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}

$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode($value);
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$paypalURL = "https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$ch = curl_init($paypalURL);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: Company name removed for security, LLC.'));
$res = curl_exec($ch);

$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

    //Payment data
    $txn_id = $_GET['txn_id'];
    $payment_gross = $_GET['mc_gross'];
    $currency_code = $_GET['mc_currency'];
    $pay_status = $_GET['payment_status'];
    $payer_email = $_GET['payer_email'];
    $date = date("m-d-y");
    $invNum = md5($date);
    $orderNum = md5($txn_id);
    $fullname = $_GET['address_name'];
    $address = $_GET['address_street'];
    $city = $_GET['address_city'];
    $state = $_GET['address_state'];
    $zip = $_GET['address_zip'];

    if($user->verify_txnid($txn_id)){
        exit();
    }else{
        $insertPayment = $user->insert_purchase($fullname,$address,$city,$state,$zip,"0000000000",$payer_email,$orderNum,$date,$txn_id,$invNum,$pay_status);
        if($insertPayment === TRUE){
            $num_cart_items = $_GET['num_cart_items'];
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $num_cart_items; $i++) {
                $order_item_name = $_GET['item_name' . $i];
                $order_item_quantity = $_GET['quantity' . $i];
                $order_item_gross_amount = $_GET['mc_gross_' . $i];
                $order_item_custom = $_GET['option_selection1_' . $i];
                $user->insert_order($txn_id, $order_item_name, $order_item_quantity, $order_item_gross_amount, $order_item_custom);

            }

        }else{
            foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
            {
                $emailtext .= $key . " = " .$value ."\n\n";
            }
            mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Insert Payment FAILED', $emailtext."\r\n".$req."\r\n".$res);
        }

    }
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

I have confirmed that the post from PayPal matches the post back to PayPal but I still get an INVALID response and none of the data gets inserted into the database. If I take the raw post data string from PayPal's initial POST and paste it into the address bar, it inserts into the database just fine. I can't figure out for the life of me why it's not inserting the data into the database on its own. My IPN history on PayPal show an html response of 500 and that its retrying.

Comment: I've had issues with the date field before. Removing it from the IPN sim sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

If IPN message you POST back does not exactly match the one PayPal sent to you, INVALID status will be occurred. You can double check if there have mess code in the IPN message you POST back, such as non-English characters. But if you still cannot find out the root cause, you have to contact PayPal technical support via https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask/ and provide PayPal transaction ID for the further checking.

Comment: I've checked and confirmed that the post back to PayPal is the exact same as the post from PayPal. So I'm stumped and confused as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: The best is post the same to PayPal technical support with details they will guide properly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exactly same problem on sandbox.

Got it working by switching off "Negative Testing" on the account profile settings and removing the date from the ipn simulator.

That simple code made it work

```
$ipn_post_data = $_POST;
// Choose url
if (array_key_exists('test_ipn', $ipn_post_data) && 1 === (int) $ipn_post_data['test_ipn']){
    $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
}else{
    $url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
}
    // Set up request to PayPal
$request = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($request, array
    (
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array('cmd' => '_notify-validate') + $ipn_post_data),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
));

    // Execute request and get response and status code
$response = curl_exec($request);
$status = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Close connection
curl_close($request);

if ($status == 200 && $response == 'VERIFIED') {
    $today = date("Y_m_d");
    $file = fopen("LogIPN.$today.txt", "ab");
    $hour = date("H:i:s T");
    fwrite($file, "Verified\r\n");
} else {
    $today = date("Y_m_d");
    $file = fopen("LogIPN.$today.txt", "ab");
    $hour = date("H:i:s T");
    fwrite($file, $response."\r\n");
    fwrite($file, $status."\r\n");
}
```

I would never use that code in production for many reasons.

Hope this can make things easy for u.